# Как превратить функцию, которая возвращает значение через callback, в future?

Tags: java, callback, асинхронность, completablefuture

Предположим у нас есть некоторая функция (и её нельзя менять):

```
void action(Consumer<Result> callback);
```

Или даже такая:

```
void action(Consumer<Result> onSuccess, Consumer<Throwable> onFail);
```

Нужно написать такую функцию, которая будет вызывать action:

```
CompletableFuture<Result> actionWrapper() {
    ...
    action(..., ...);
    ...
}
```

но при этом `Callback`'и будут навешиваться через `CompletableFuture`, а не через параметры внутреннего `action`. В принципе разные велосипедные или костыльные варианты я и сам могу написать, поэтому интересует более-менее стандартное решение (возможно через какую-то плюс-минус популярную либу).

Answer (score 0):

В `actionWrapper` создаете пустой `CompletableFuture<Result> resultCompletableFuture`, который будет получать результат, и два колбэка, которые будут переданы в `action`. Эти колбэки при вызове должны вызывать методы `complete` и `completeExceptionally` у объекта `resultCompletableFuture`. Соответственно, при вызове одного из этих колбэков функцией `action` `resultCompletableFuture` будет завершён с результатом или с ошибкой.

```
CompletableFuture<Result> actionWrapper() {
    CompletableFuture<Result> resultCompletableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();

    Consumer<Result> handler = result -> resultCompletableFuture.complete(result);
    Consumer<Throwable> errorHandler = throwable -> resultCompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(throwable);

    action(handler, errorHandler);

    return resultCompletableFuture;
}
```

В качестве колбэков можно передать сами методы `resultCompletableFuture::complete` и `resultCompletableFuture::completeExceptionally`, тогда функция сократится до 3 строк:

```
CompletableFuture<Result> actionWrapper() {
    var result = new CompletableFuture<Result>();
    action(result::complete, result::completeExceptionally);
    return result;
}
```

Проблема с вариантами выше в том, что они не асинхронные, т.е. код ниже вызова `actionWrapper` не продолжит выполняться, пока не закончится выполнение функции `action`.

Чтобы работало асинхронно, нужно вызов `action` обернуть в `CompletableFuture.runAsync`, возврат результата цепляем через `.thenCompose`, и результат всей цепочки вызовов возвращаем из `actionWrapper` через `return`:

```
private static CompletableFuture<Result> actionWrapper() {
    var result = new CompletableFuture<Result>();
    return CompletableFuture
            .runAsync(() -> action(result::complete, result::completeExceptionally))
            .thenCompose(_void -> result);
}
```

Вызов:

```
actionWrapper()
        .thenAccept(result -> {
            // Обрабатываем результат
        })
        .exceptionally(throwable -> {
            // Обрабатываем ошибку
            return null;
        });
```

Также вариант для `action` с одним колбэком, но которая может бросить исключение, которое нужно отловить и передать в `CompletableFuture`:

```
CompletableFuture<Result> actionWrapper() {
    var result = new CompletableFuture<Result>();
    return CompletableFuture
            .runAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    action(result::complete);
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    result.completeExceptionally(t);
                }
            })
            .thenCompose(_void -> result);
}
```

---

Обобщенный вариант врапперов, в которые можно передать любые функции вида `action`:

```
<T> CompletableFuture<T> actionWrapper(BiConsumer<Consumer<T>, Consumer<Throwable>> action) {
    var result = new CompletableFuture<T>();
    return CompletableFuture
            .runAsync(() -> action.accept(result::complete, result::completeExceptionally))
            .thenCompose(_void -> result);
}

<T> CompletableFuture<T> actionWrapper(Consumer<Consumer<T>> action) {
    var result = new CompletableFuture<T>();
    return CompletableFuture
            .runAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    action.accept(result::complete);
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    result.completeExceptionally(t);
                }
            })
            .thenCompose(_void -> result);
}
```

Пример вызова:

```
actionWrapper(this::action)
        .thenAccept(result -> {
            // Обрабатываем результат
        })
        .exceptionally(throwable -> {
            // Обрабатываем ошибку
            return null;
        });
```